# Dr Cristina Sanchez shows prior art for patent [US8790719]

Tags: us8790719

In reference to the patent: [US8790719](https://www.google.com/patents/US8790719)

Dr Cristina Sanchez shows prior art [video](https://www.facebook.com/illegallyhealed/videos/vb.645148008872123/1107576179295968/?type=2&theater)

Comment: It isn't quite clear what you are asking for. My guess (upon which my answer is based) is that you are asking whether the video linked provides prior art to the cited patent.

Answer (score 1):

The video is dated April 23rd, 2016. The priority date for the patent is March 12th, 2010. For something to be considered prior art to this patent it needs to have been published before March 12th, 2010. Perhaps you can find specific publications from Dr. Sanchez which predate the priority date of the patent. Also, you need to consider the claims. Unusually, this patent has but one claim.

> 1. A method of treating a human suffering from a glioma consisting essentially of administering therapeutically effective amounts of
>      isolated or highly purified tetrahydrocannabinol and cannabidiol,
>      together with temozolomide to said human to treat said glioma in said
>      human.

Can you show specifically a publication (by Dr. Sanchez or others) that employs the combination of tetrahydrocannabinol, cannabidiol and temozolomide in the treatment of glioma? If so, then there may be grounds for invalidation, but the video only mentions tetrahydrocannabinol and cannabidiol, not temozolomide. Because the claim utilizes all three compounds, it should not preclude the use of just tetrahydrocannabinol and cannabidiol for the treatment of glioma.